# Missing 'secret_token' and 'secret_key_base' for 'production' environment (Puma)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma, secret-key

I don't understand why my secret_token and secret_key_base aren't being read by Puma. The app is being deployed through Capistrano, Nginx and Puma.

secrets.yml

```
development:
  secret_key_base: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  secret_token: XXXXXXXXXXX

test:
  secret_key_base: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  secret_token: <%= ENV["SECRET_TOKEN"] %>
```

My .gitignore file **is not** blocking my secrets.yml file, yet everytime I try to connect to my server I am told `An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.`

And my application log tells me that I am `Missing 'secret_token' and 'secret_key_base' for 'production' environment`

Full application log

```
=== puma startup: 2016-04-05 07:00:04 -0400 ===
2016-04-05 07:00:09 -0400: Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing     `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`>
/home/deploy/apps/IASAS_site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
/home/deploy/apps/IASAS_site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
/home/deploy/apps/IASAS_site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
/home/deploy/apps/IASAS_site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/home/deploy/apps/IASAS_site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
/home/deploy/apps/IASAS_site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/server.rb:561:in `handle_request'
/home/deploy/apps/IASAS_site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
/home/deploy/apps/IASAS_site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
/home/deploy/apps/IASAS_site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:111:in `call'
/home/deploy/apps/IASAS_site/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:111:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Please help!

Comment: Let me guess: you did not bother to set the environment variables `SECRET_KEY_BASE` and `SECRET_TOKEN`?

Comment: I set my environment variables and am still receiving the same errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your configuration file the answer seems to be quite obvious.

In production Puma takes these values from two environment variables (*SECRET_KEY_BASE* and *SECRET_TOKEN*). You need to define these environment variables on your *production* server.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04, do I set these by running `export SECRET_KEY_BASE='bundle exec rake secret'` and `export SECRET_TOKEN='bundle exec rake secret'?
After this should I redeploy and restart nginx?

This is my first time deploying an app, sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Yes for SECRET_KEY_BASE. I have no idea what SECRET_TOKEN is for you.

Comment: I set my SECRET_KEY_BASE and SECRET_TOKEN through the export function, used echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE and echo$SECRET_TOKEN to check to make sure they were correct, then redeployed through `cap production deploy` and still received the same errors.

Comment: You need to set the env var for the proper user (the one running the web process).

Comment: Please elaborate on how I should do this... I'm so lost